# How to retrieve SQL Product Key from an existing installation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, registry

We want to retrieve product key of SQL server. 
We have multiple versions of SQL and understood that product key's path changes for each version. We don't want to hard code the path hence searching for a generic logic. 
As every version has different folder structure to store product key, we are using Switch statement as

```
switch (majorVersion)
        {
            case "8":
                registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Registration";              
                break;
            case "9":
                registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\ProductId";        
                break;
            case "10":
                registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup";           
                break;
            case "11":
                registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\ClientSetup";                
                break;
            case "12":
                registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\ClientSetup";
                break;
            case "13":
                 registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Setup";
                break;
            case "13.1":
                registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Setup\Client_Components_Full\1033";
                break;
            case "14":
                registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Setup";
                break;
            default:
                registryPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion";
                break;
        }
```

Want to avoid this switch and retrieve key without specifying hard coded path.

How can we get correct product key of any installed sql version?

( Looking for sql script solution only and not power shell.)

Comment: This might work if you can run it on the sql server.
https://www.sqlservergeeks.com/t-sql-script-to-find-the-cd-key-from-registry/

Comment: Thanks for the hint @JonTout. But in this example the path is specified upfront. How can we get a path dynamically depend on any installed version? As each version has different path. Updated my question with one sample, can you please have a look and guide further?

Answer (score 1):

The trick to do this in a dynamic way is to look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names` and read the value of the subkeys. e.g. MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER, SSRS, ...

Use the subkey value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\Setup` to read in the `Version` value. The version number is needed to change behavior for older versions.

When the first two digits are higher than 11, read in the `DigitalProductID` value at the same location.

Here is some C# [example code](https://github.com/MaxxVolk/MiscellaneousProjects/blob/7fd49cd8bd19c1c3b255c08d5b82fc9647e6369a/SQLProductKey/Program.cs#L18). It is further explained on [Max Volkov's blog](https://maxcoreblog.com/2019/05/09/accidental-task-recover-sql-server-product-key-from-existing-installation/). It outlines some concerns regarding the base24 decoding of the binary key too.

It is possible to recreate the code in T-SQL, but to me it does not seem the ideal language for all this.

There is a cmdlet [Get-DbaProductKey](https://docs.dbatools.io/Get-DbaProductKey), part of https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools.

And since this page ends up high in search results, here is another way to retrieve the key:

> Learn how to find the product key for SQL Server Reporting Services
> (SSRS) 2017 and 2019 so you can install your server in a production
> environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/find-reporting-services-product-key-ssrs

Answer (score -3):

This reads from the registry:

```
Declare @Val nvarchar(4000) 

Exec master .dbo.xp_instance_regread
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',
    N'ProductCode', 
    @Val output

Select @Val As ProductCode
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The product code describes the version of the product. The product key is the license key provided by microsoft when purchasing a paid version of the software and is used to authorize the use of the software.

Comment: This is correct, I tried it